# Не получается сделать строчный вывод по 2 статьи

Tags: php, html, css

Теперь правильно задам вопрос

Проблема в том, что я хочу сделать вывод по 2 статьи в строке (по горизонтали), в данный момент выводится по 1 статье по вертикали. Код вывода:

```
printf ("
<table align='center' class='lesson'>
    <tr>
        <td class='lesson_title'>
            <p class='lesson_name'>
                <a class='a' href='view_obzor.php?id=%s'>%s</a>
            </p>
            <p class='lesson_adds'>Дата добавления: %s</p>
            <p class='lesson_adds'>Автор урока: %s</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class='lessons_text'>%s</p>
            <p class='lesson_view'>Просмотров: %s &nbsp;&nbsp; Рейтинг:
                <img src='images/%s.gif'>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
", $myrow["id"], $myrow["title"], $myrow["date"], $myrow["author"], $myrow["description"], $myrow["view"], $r);
```

Код css:

```
 .lesson {
     border: 1px solid#aec3f8;
     border - radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
     width: 35 %;
 }
```

Изображения как есть:

[image]

Хотелось бы добиться вот такого результата. Примерно так там линиями все указано:

[image]

Заранее большое спасибо, надеюсь правильно описал суть проблемы.

С уважением, StrannicK.

Answer (score 2):

К примеру выше могу посоветовать добавить `style="vertical-align:top"`. Используйте лучше блочную верстку.

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}.lesson {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Если вам так нравится табличная верстка, тогда каждую оберните вашу конструкцию в еще одну таблицу из двух ячеек (td) в строках. Пример:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><table align='center' class='lesson'></table></td>
<td><table align='center' class='lesson'></table></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Второй вариант. **css:**

```
 .lesson {
     float:left;
 }
```

В этом случае ширина таблицы lesson должна быть прописана в стилях и должна быть меньше половины родительского элемента.

Comment: хехе еще хуже стало, почти то, но вылазиет из блока

http://s017.radikal.ru/i401/1205/3b/557fdbe5190c.jpg

Comment: Хуже стало после чего? Судя по сдвигу и разной ширине колонок, решили воспользоваться еще одной таблицей. Поэтому проверьте внимательно все ли теги закрыты. И ширину ячеек родительской таблицы лучше явно указать.